# Is it possible for <input> input value not binding to formControl, so that I can submit other value in angular 4 reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

A simple part of the code is below.

```
 <label class="center-block">Name:
     <input class="form-control" (change)="searchUserBYName()" formControlName="name">
 </label>
 <div *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="selectUser(user)">{{user.name}}</div>
```

Any change to this input will trigger the searchUserByName() function, and this function will return a list of user object, which is given to "users":

```
{name: "fullname", id: "userid"}
```

The user list will show, and I can select the user I want. The selectUser() function will store this user into a variable called "selectedUser" and update the fullname of the user to input textbox(This is required, can not be changed). But how can I binding the formControlName to the id of the user? which mean, when I click the submit button, how can I submit the id of the user but not the name of the user? Another requirement is I can not add more visible element to this whole form. 
I have thought about passing the user id in the component function. Just let the name passed by "submit". But there is one shortage. I can input the value of the input box without selecting another user from user list and submit. In this case, the id is null. 
I don't know if I clarify this problem clearly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with: But how can I binding the formControlName to the id of the user?

Comment: In the component,  there are " name: new FormControl()". When I click submit, the name of this form is related to the <input> value. But I want the formcontrol bind to the id of the user, not the name.